# Python Dynamic Execution

Tags: python, dynamic

I have a list of dictionary items stored in variable List_dicts, and I have to write a selected list of items from the above list into a file. given below my python function:

```
def write_items(List_dicts,key_list):
  #List_dicts contains the list if dicts
  #key_list contains the key separated by comma
  k_list=key_list.split(',')
  write_string=''
  for i in k_list:
    write_string=write_string+"item['"+i+"'],"
  f=open('log.txt','w')
  for item in List_dicts:
    f.write(write_string[0:len(write_string)-1]) #this should write item['key1'],item['key2'],item['key3']..,item['keyn'] not the value of string 'write_string'
  f.close()
```

Is this possible in anyways? I was inspired from SQL dynamic execute quires.

Comment: use csv with dictwriter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

edit : judging from your code, your function doesn't appear to be writing anything related to the contents of `dict`s. you are writing `write_string[0:len(write_string)-1]` to your file for each dict you got(which is just a copy of your `write_string` without last trailing comma) and the `write_string` has nothing to with items in your dict, it's just selected keys from the `key_list`.

there is a python module, `csv`, with a class called [`DictWriter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter), which is suitable for your job.

```
import csv

def write_dicts(dicts, keys, filename):

   with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:
       writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, keys, extrasaction='ignore')
       for d in dicts:
           writer.writerow(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but if I do, here's what you should be using:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html

Basically it allows you to store python objects in files.
Here's a quick example you should have a look at:
http://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle

Answer (score 0):

Apart from being better off using the `csv` module, what you did wrong was that you overcomplicated things.

You already have a list of keys to write, so just loop *directly* over those keys:

```
def write_items(List_dicts, key_list):
    k_list = key_list.split(',')
    with open('log.txt','w') as f:
        for item in List_dicts:
          for key in k_list:
              f.write(item[key])
```